# How to watch MFC Class field in .dmp debugging with WinDbg?

Tags: c++, debugging, mfc, windbg

I have a crash dump (.dmp) with the MFC application.
The application contains MFC Class such as the container (CMap).
I confirmed that the application crash to refer some containers.
But,,,I have a crash dump only the release version,
and the application error has not been able to repro.
So I would like to know the way to watch MFC class container with WinDbg.

Appreciate any helps/pointers.

Comment: "watch" makes no sense in this context.  A minidump is a frozen copy of the state of the program when it bombed.

Comment: My description was incorrect. I would like to check the members of container in a memory snapshot.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is kind of confusing, but I believe what you want is the 'dt' command in windbg.

Basic usage is like this:

dt MY_TYPE_HERE 0xFOODBEEF

This will show the the contents of memory 0xFOODBEEF displayed as type MY_TYPE_HERE.

Additional options can be found in the windbg help file.